# How does the decimal number system differ from others?

Tags: numbers, decimal, system

To convert a number from decimal to another, we use division.
To convert from some system to decimal, we use multiplication by digits.
Moreover, if we want to translate from one (non-decimal) to another (non-decimal), then we need a decimal ...
Why is the decimal system so special?

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you are talking about?

Comment: I want to translate from octal number system to octal. To do this, I have to convert an octal number to decimal by multiplication, and then convert to octal from decimal by division. And so for any systems. Why is there always a decimal number system in this algorithm, although it seems to be no different from the others.

Comment: You could convert octal to binary to octal w/o using decimal at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing a particular *representation* from a number's *value*, and the *value* with the base it is usually expressed in (decimal), which is the only thing special about it.